# Adding object to a list, changes all other list objects

Tags: c#, list

I’m trying to add animals to my animal list, but the values of the last added animal will be all the animals in the list.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
public bool AddAnimal(Animal animal)
        {
            animals.Add(animal); 
            return true;
        } 

Animal animal = new Animal();
private void btnAddAnimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animal.AnimalSize = Size.large;
            animal.Carnivore = true;
            AddAnimal(animal);
        }
```

This is the list:
Size    Carnivore
-  Large    True

```
private void btnAddAnimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animal.AnimalSize = Size.large;
            animal.Carnivore = false;
            AddAnimal(animal);
        }
```

This is what happens with my animals list after I add an Herbivore:

- Size        Carnivore

  - Large       false
  - Large       false

Comment: C# sorry i'll add it right away

Comment: `animal` is always point to the same memory address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't actually add a new Animal, you're merely modifying the one you have. If you want to add a new animal, you have to create a new object:

```
private void btnAddAnimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Animal animal = new Animal();
  animal.AnimalSize = Size.large;
  animal.Carnivore = true;
  AddAnimal(animal);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You create the animal *once* (outside your method), and then only change its properties. Thus, your list looks like this:

```
      +--------+
  +-> | Animal |
  |   +--------+
  |    ^    ^
  |    |    |
 [0], [1], [2], ...
```

They all point to the *same* animal. That's obviously not what you want. What you want is this:

```
      +--------+
  +-> | Animal |
  |   +--------+
  |              +--------+
  |         +--> | Animal |
  |         |    +--------+
 [0], [1], [2], ...
       |
       v
      +--------+
      | Animal |
      +--------+
```

To fix this, create a **new animal** each time:

```
// Animal animal = new Animal(); <-- we don't need this any more

private void btnAddAnimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Animal animal = new Animal();  // <-- but we need it here

    animal.AnimalSize = Size.large;
    animal.Carnivore = true;
    AddAnimal(animal);
}
```